# Response(xls file) of a POST Rest is corrupted using fileSaver.js 's saveAs method(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, http-post, filesaver.js

Below is the detail of JAVA rest service which downloads a file from server:
Method prototype:

```
@POST
@Path("/prop/export")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response exportItemsToFile(Map<String, String> params);
```

The Response is build from byte array in its implementation:

```
Response.ok(someByteArray)
```

I am using `FileSaver.saveAs` to download the response in a xls file using below code

```
var requestUri = '/wtk/rc/v1/pfm/prop/export';
                var payload={"context":addCtx,"language":addLang,"country":addCountry,"swimlane":addSL};
                $http.post(requestUri, payload, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                }).success(function (data) {
                    var blob = new Blob([data],{type : 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
                    var fileName = addLang+"_"+addCountry+".xls";
                    filesaver.saveAs(blob,fileName);
                }).error(function () {
                    //download failed
                });
```

The response which is xls file is corrupt using the above code. **

> It is because the promise returned by $http.post have blank response
>   in case of if rest client produces octet-stream

**

But if I use some rest client like Postman, and select "Send and Download" option and save the response as xls. It is coming up fine.

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Comment: `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` as a *response*. That's unusual. Did you perhaps mean to put that on `@Consumes` instead, so your `params` could be received as form data (or JSON)?

Comment: Why are you returning *bytes* as `application/json`? Did you perhaps mean to say `@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")`, or `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`? --- And since it's binary data, `charset=utf-8` should not be there.

Comment: I corrected by question